# expected value $E[X]$ from MGF.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

How to differentiate this 
$$\sum_{x=a}^{a+n-1}\frac1ne^{tx}$$
for $m(t)$ and find $E[X]$ from this?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the expression given is the moment generating function of a discrete, uniform random variable. You can differentiate (with respect to $t$) term by term to get $m'(t) = \sum_{x=a}^{a+n-1} \frac{1}{n}xe^{tx}$. From here, set $t=0$. Then you are left with an arithmetic series to evaluate.

Comment: so if i put t=0 i will be left with $m'(0) = \frac1n \sum_{x=a}^{a+x-1}x$ . how to get E[x] from this? what is does E[x] mean

Comment: That right. $E[X] = m'(0)$. To see why, recall the definition $m(t) = E[e^{tX}] = E[1 + tX + t^2X^2/2 + \ldots] = 1 + tE[X] + t^2E[X^2]/2 + \ldots$, using the Taylor expansion for the exponential function and the fact that taking expectations is linear. Differentiating we get that $m'(t) = E[X] + tE[X^2] + \ldots$, and finally setting $t=0$ we get $m'(0) = E[X]$

Comment: It means my expected value E[x] = 1/n * [ a + (a+1) +. . . + (a+n-1)]

Comment: Correct. Can you right this in a simplified way using arithmetic series? The answer you get by doing so might be more intuitive